# display the value of a select field in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have a form with a `select field.`
When the user select a `value`, I want to `display this value`.

html is:

```
<select name="number" id="number">
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="2">4</option>
</select>

<div id="test">2</div>
```

and jquery is

```
$(function() {
    $('#number').change(function() {
        var test = $('#test');
        if($('select[name="number"]').val() == '4'){
            test.html('select 4');
        }else{
            test.html('select 2');
        }
    });    
});
```

It's just working for the fist select (with the wrong value though) then it doesn't want to work.

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomlazada/4sRmG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any option with value `4`

```
if($('select[name="number"]').val() == '4'){
```

change it to

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gCaY9/)</kbd>

```
if($('select[name="number"]').val() == '2'){
```

**Problem**

```
<option value="2">4</option>
//             ^ value is 2 not 4
```

Or

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gCaY9/)</kbd>

If you want to do it with text of option

```
if ($('select[name="number"] option:selected').text() == '4')
```

Answer (score 0):

You confuse the **text inside** the `<option>` (which is `4`) with the **value** of that `<option>` (which is `2`).

To solve your problem do **one** of 3:

1). Change your html to (so option will have value `4`, not just inner text `4`):

```
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
```

2). **Or** your jQuery code (so you select option with value `2`):

```
if($('select[name="number"]').val() == '2'){
```

3). **Or** your jQuery code (better not check by text, but if you want to keep the html "as is" and still use `4` for some reason):

```
if($('select[name="number"] option:selected').text() == '4'){
```

Also, as **@Dinu** mentionted, consider the shorter notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try below its working fine. You wrote lot of unnecessary code

```
$('#number').change(function(){
    $('#test').html('Selected: ' + $('#number').val());
});
```